# Adding SKU as body class in Woocmmerce for Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to be able to target certain product-pages with CSS based on the SKU of the product they have on. Therefore I need to add the SKU as a body class for all Woocommerce products. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I'd strongly recommend that you head over to [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an' idea of how SO works. SO is not a free coding service neither a tutorial place :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add Woocommerce body classes
add_filter('body_class','sku_woocommerce_body_classes');
function sku_woocommerce_body_classes($classes){
    global $post;
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );
    if ( $product->product_type == 'simple'); 
    $classes[] = $product->get_sku();
    return $classes;
}
```

You weren't clear on what type of pages to target, but the if statement will get you where you need to go in order to target them.